# How to pass different objects in the same function

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, json

```js
object1 = {
  "Name": "foo",
  "age": 20
};

object2 = {
  "name": "someone",
  "age": 21
};

function person() {
  console.log(`My self ${name} i am ${age} old`);
}

person();
```

Here, I just want to pass different objects as a parameter of the same function. When I click a button object1 will be passed.  When I click another button object2 will be passed. But the problem is without changing a literal expression [like object1.name to object2.name] to execute this function

Comment: `function person(a)` ... `person(object1);` ... guess what `a` will be in function person?

Comment: Please consider reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#function_parameters

Comment: Do you need help in solving this in any particular library like react or just want to know how to call this function with two different object?

Comment: @B45i No, I just want to know how to call this function with two different object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const object1 = {
  "name": "foo",
  "age": 20
};

const object2 = {
  "name": "someone",
  "age": 21
};

function person({name, age}) {
  console.log(`My self ${name} i am ${age} old`);
}

person(object1);
person(object2);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can call person(object1) or person(object2), and your function can be something like :

```
function person(obj) {
    console.log(`My self ${obj.name} i am ${obj.age} old`);
  }
```

Comment: yes! But I don't want to change the literal expression every single time

Comment: @MuralikumarJ why would you need to do that?

Comment: Yeah, so you can use bind fn like : 
const _person = person.bind(object1)
and update your function with this.name and this.age,
you can call _person() as function.

Comment: @evolutionxbox This is an example program but the problem is the same. I just want to know how to call this function with two different objects.  Because I use the onclick attribute to assign a function there I will pass an object as a param, I want to execute a  function when a button gets clicked. that's why?

Comment: @MuralikumarJ that doesn't really answer my question. Why does the solution in this answer mean you would need to change the literal every time?

Comment: @MuralikumarJ I agree with evolutionxbox here - this solution is the right way to write a function that takes an object as the parameter. Not sure why you think this is wrong.